# Polymer 2.0 async and getComputedStyle

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

In our polymer1.0 component, we had this:

```
attached: function () 
{
    var something=this.getComputedStyleValue("--flxs-" + prop)
    this.async(function()
    {
        // do some work here.
    });
}
```

In 2.0, both this.getComputedStyleValue  this.async is not defined.

Any idea what is the alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Polymer.Async](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/api/namespaces/Polymer.Async) seems like the alternate to `this.async`.

For `getComputedStyleValue` you can try [StyleGather](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/api/namespaces/Polymer.StyleGather), but i doubt it'll work.

Otherwise, [LegacyMixin](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/api/mixins/Polymer.LegacyElementMixin) contains all the old methods.

Comment: Alone `Polymer.Async` doesn't work. Further namespace needs to be added. [API Reference](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/api/namespaces/Polymer.Async)